# Connection to mongoose causes ECONNREFUSE

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a file database.coffee containing only two lines 
 `mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase'`

When running `coffee database.coffee` I get the following output:

```
/SOMEPATH/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:236
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                        ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
```

What could be causing this error ?

Comment: Is your local MongoDB server running and accepting connection on the `localhost` IP address?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, how could I check that ?

Comment: Be sure you've [installed MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production) first, and make sure [it's working](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/).